# Symfony 3 FileUpload

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying implement file uploading functionality for my app with Symfony 3.
I have a product entiry, that have relation to File entiry.
Part of Product:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\File", mappedBy="product")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"weight" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $files;
```

and field on form:

```
     ->add('files', FileType::class, array('multiple'=> true, 'data_class'=> 'AppBundle\Entity\File'));

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
    ));
}
```

As you can see, I'm set data_class.

and in controller I'm trying handle form

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setAddedBy($this->getUser());
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, null);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 
    ...
```

and I have an error:

> Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\File", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" given

If I drop data_class mapping I have no error and no object, just array. 
How I can resolve this error, how to transform UploadedFile to File (Entiry). I'm trying to create Transformer, but I just got the ProductEntiry class, and as result can't process it, becouse it's without files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I'll get to the point, just one suggest. In line:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, null);
```

I would provide `$product` variable so it will be automatically filled with data instead of creating new one. So it should be changed to :

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
```

Ok, now, the problem occurs, because you probably have in your `Product` class a setter like:

```
public function addFile(AppBundle\Entity\File $file) { ... }
```

Then, after successful validation, the form tries to fill instance of `Product` class with data from the form, which contains Symfony's `UploadedFile` class instance. I hope you understand that.

Now, you have (at least) two possible solutions.

You can set `"mapped" => false` option for the file field. That will stop form from trying to put it's value into underlying object (`Product` instance).

After doing that you can handle the value on your own, which is handle file upload, create `AppBundle/Entity/File` instance and put it into `$product` variable via setter.

That the *lazy* solution, but if you would like to do the same in other forms, you will have to copy the code to every controller that needs it. So it's easier only for *one time usage*.

The right solution would be to convert `UploadedFile` to you `File` object with a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). It's a longer topic to talk about and exact solution depends on your data flow that you want to achieve. Therefore if you want to do this right, read about [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) in Symfony's docs first.

I promise that you will thank yourself later if you do that the right way. I've spent some time on understanding Symfony Form Component including Data Transformers and solved a similar issue that way. Now it pays back. I have reusable image upload form that handles even removing previously uploaded files in edit forms.

P.S.
It's *"entity"*, not *"entiry"*. You've wrote *"entiry"* twice, so I'm just saying FYI.